# Bitmap not parsed as a function variable

Tags: c#, bitmapdata

I got some simplistic code to get an average color out of 5 bitmaps.

```
    private Bitmap AVG5Bitmaps(Bitmap a, Bitmap b, Bitmap c, Bitmap d, Bitmap e)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(c);

        for (int x = 0; x < result.Width; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < result.Height; y++) 
            {
                int r = (
                        (int)a.GetPixel(x, y).R + 
                        (int)b.GetPixel(x, y).R +
                        (int)c.GetPixel(x, y).R +
                        (int)d.GetPixel(x, y).R +
                        (int)e.GetPixel(x, y).R) / 5;

                int g = (
                         (int)a.GetPixel(x, y).G +
                         (int)b.GetPixel(x, y).G +
                         (int)c.GetPixel(x, y).G +
                         (int)d.GetPixel(x, y).G +
                         (int)e.GetPixel(x, y).G) / 5;

                int b =  (
                         (int)a.GetPixel(x, y).B +
                         (int)b.GetPixel(x, y).B +
                         (int)c.GetPixel(x, y).B +
                         (int)d.GetPixel(x, y).B +
                         (int)e.GetPixel(x, y).B) / 5;

                  result.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(r,g,b))
            }
        }
       return result; 
    }
```

The strange thing is that `a.GetPixel(x, y).R` is recognized, however with `b.GetPixel(x, y).R` gives an error:

> Cannot use local variable b before it is declared

`b` is not even seen as a bitmap object? I don't get it, why does the code work with `a` but not with `b`. Is this a bug with Visual Studio 2010?

on request updated the question with complete function code

Comment: I strongly believe that this is your mistake, you are looking at wrong piece of code, or wrong version or something like that. Because in your fragment b is not even a local variable.

Comment: This code does not give that compiler error. Please create an [mcve]. I'm sure you've got some accolades or parentheses mismatched.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code for the function, and to me it shows that error. Which i think it shouldnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
int b =
```

is hiding the parameter `b`, thus you are trying to access that variable within its assignmnent. Thus the error. Rename the variable.

Comment: In his current example that line is not seen... Ahh.. he changed his example :)

Comment: Yeah you got me...  thanks, renamed to bb it works now

Comment: @user you may want to consider using more meaningful variable names.